Directus - decrypt Static Token in NextJS
I´m using the static Token for authenticated Queries. With logging in i want to save the Static Token within the session, but I can´t find a way to decrypt the Token. I´m saving the Token in the session already, but i´m just getting ****** as a value.
I tried to decrypt it with jwt decode, but the Token doesn´t seem to be in the correct jwt Format.
This is my current Code:

import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { options } from "./[...nextauth]/options";
import { readItems } from "@directus/sdk";
import directus from "../../../../lib/directus";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { decode } from "next-auth/jwt";

export async function getUserInfo() {
    const session = await getServerSession(options);
    let userId = '';
    let isAdmin = false;
    let isActiveSession = false;
    let isUserActive = false;
    let isUserRejected = false;
    let isUserBlocked = false;
    let accessToken = null;
    let userMainToken = null;

    if (session && session.user && session.user.id && session.user.id.id) {
        userId = session.user.id.id;
        const userMainToken = session.user.id.token;
      
    }


    const res = await fetch(`*********/users/${userId}`, {
        method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${userMainToken}`,
      }
    });
    const resTemp = await res.json();
    const userContent = resTemp.data;


    const adminID = 'e2895cd6-42e0-450f-9690-9b140572548e';

    if (userContent?.role === adminID) {
        isAdmin = true;
    }


    if (session) {
        isActiveSession = true;
    }

    if(userContent?.aktiver_nutzer) {
        isUserActive = true;
    }

 
    

    return { userId, isAdmin, userContent, isActiveSession, isUserActive, accessToken };
}






My current Workaround is to pass the generated static token to a normal Textinput which can be queried like any other „normal“ Text-Input field. This works perfect, but obviously isn’t the nicest way (still a workaround)
